# Ending a TKinter class method without killing the main thread

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I've scoured the internet on this one and haven't come up with anything, so please excuse me if this is a dumb question, but...

I've written a Tkinter class that takes a .xlsx file as input for one of its processes. You press a button and it uses TKFileDialog.askopenfile() to pop the familiar-looking file input dialog. However, if a user hits cancel, the input is NoneType, the file doesn't open, and the TKinter window terminates with a TypeError.

```
def GUIDocPullRename(self):
    indir = self.e1.get()
    Tab = askopenfile()
    try:
        tBook = xlrd.open_workbook(Tab)
    except TypeError:
        self.text.insert(END, "Canceled")
        #Insert method-ender here
```

I want to insert something in the exception catch that stops the GUIDocPullRename from continuing, but allows the parent TKinter process to continue running so the user can specify another file without having to re-run the whole program. Is it possible or am I just being a silly newb?

Error is this, when the try/except is excluded:

```
 Exception in Tkinter callback
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1470, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "P:/Administrative/IT/Scripting/BillsPython/PdfMerger.py", line 102, in GUIDocPullRename
    tBook = xlrd.open_workbook(Tab)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py", line 394, in open_workbook
    f = open(filename, "rb")
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, NoneType found
```

Comment: Please post the actual error.

Comment: Can't you just test `if Tab is None:`, and return? Also, what does your question have to with respect to multithreading?

Comment: ...You're right, of course. How could I have forgotten something so simple, much less taken it this far? Also, maybe I'm misunderstanding multithreading, but I thought TKinter called its child methods using multithreading.

Comment: @BillMoylan: no, tkinter doesn't use threads at all.

Comment: Oh. Well, RIP first impression...